# Read text file as a static resource and display in a VF page?

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

I need to place my text file as a static resource in salesforce org. Then I need to read that text file and display the contents in a VF page.

In this way whenever we want to update the text contents in a VF page, we can easily change the file contents without touching the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The StaticResource object is readable via a normal SOQL query.

Add a property to your controller that queries the static resource and returns its body assuming the body is text:

```
public String textFromSomeUniqueName {
    get {
        StaticResource sr = [
                select Body
                from StaticResource
                where Name = 'SomeUniqueName'
                ];
        return sr.Body.toString();
    }
}
```

The page can then output the text using:

```
{!textFromSomeUniqueName}
```

**PS**

If you want to output HTML content use:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!textFromSomeUniqueName}" escape="false"/>
```

Comment: one word ....AWESOME !!!!...it works smoothly....Thanks Keith C

Comment: Is it possible to maintain the line breaks in static resource ?

Comment: @samir Line breaks can be included in static SOQL in Apex as shown above. If you mean in the static resource content then the answer is yes there too.

Comment: I imported a body but its shown only in single line on vf page. I had to use iframe to show the content as it is in static resource

Comment: @Samir HTML does not respect normal text line breaks. You may have to replace those on the fly or when the content is written with e.g. `<br/>`.

Comment: I tested wit `<br />` as well, even then was not able to show the line breaks. Tried changing the escape to true/false of output text.No success!!

Comment: @Samir See the PS I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question and answers ([Editing a Static Resource via Apex with Metadata API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/editing-a-static-resource-via-apex-with-metadata-api))

You'll need to use the metadata api to achieve this.

Comment: I think the requirement is to only read from Visualforce; the updating (probably) is to be be done through e.g. Setup.

Comment: I have checked there....but its for creating updating and deleting usign metadata API...!!
I want to read text file saved as a static resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the static resource then you can use simple SOQL

```
List<StaticResource> sr = [Select body, name from StaticResource where Name = 'xx'];
```

Comment: public class Myclass {

    public list<StaticResource> getGetText() {
        return [Select body, name from StaticResource where Name = 'pranTXT'];
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------------
<apex:page controller="Myclass">
<apex:outputText value="{0}">
    <apex:param value="{!getGetText}"/>
</apex:outputText>
</apex:page>
------------------------------------------
Tried this ...but its throwing error...

Comment: Error: Myclass Compile Error: The property String getText is referenced by Visualforce Page (TestPage) in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. at line 8 column 19